# Problem with references; have to manually copy dll's to prevent error every build

Tags: c#, .net

I have just started my project but have run into problems which is preventing me from working.

The error is:

> The type or namespace name
>   'NHibernateImportLib' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

Now, if i set '*Copy Local*' to False for the NHibernate reference in '*NHibernateImportLib*' it build but later i have to copy my NHibernate dll to my output directory for the application to work properly.

What is going on here?

Comment: You have added the reference in the project, right?

Comment: @Erik: Have you added the dll inside the folder(which is inside the project)?

Comment: @dhinesh: Im not sure what you mean. In my application project i have referenced my class library project (this is the 'NHibernateImportLib' project), and in this project setting 'Copy Local' to NHibernate changes the build outcome.

Comment: Are you saying that just changing `Copy Local` to `false` without any code change caused the project to build successfully? Maybe you have multiple versions of the NHibernate assembly. Did you try removing and re-adding the reference?

Comment: Wow, bizarre problem.  Build + Clean to get a better diagnostic, maybe.

Comment: Yes, I have. Note that NHibernate is not used in my application project, only in the referenced one.

Comment: Can you post the code that does not compile when you have a reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mismatching target frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Is the assembly added to `GAC`? It might be possible that on your deployment target machine this assembly is not present in `GAC` and hence it works only when you copy it into the local directory.